# I get an error when trying to write `message.channel.send(embed)` in discord.js, and says cannot read sent

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so i have this code

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Color = `RANDOM`;
const Fetch = require("node-fetch");

module.exports = {
    name: "britishmeme",
    description: "Send A Meme!",
    async execute(client, message, args) {

        const res = await Fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/BritishMemes/random/.json`);

        const json = await res.json();

        if (!json[0]) {
            return message.channel.send(`Error`);
        } else {

            const data = json[0].data.children[0].data;

            const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(Color)
                .setURL(`https://reddit.com${data.permalink}`)
                .setTitle(data.title)
                .setDescription(`Author: ${data.author}`)
                .setImage(data.url)
                .setFooter(` ${data.ups || 0} |  ${data.downs || 0} |  ${data.num_comments || 0}`)
                .setTimestamp();

            return message.channel.send(Embed);
        }
    }
};
```

but i keep getting an error which states cannot read property send as shown in the following message. `(node:614) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined at Object.execute (/home/runner/economybot/commands/fun/britishmeme.js:16:27)` I am running discord.js 12.3.3 How do i fix this?

Comment: What did you get at your ```message.channel```properties ? Try using ```console.log(message.channel);``` and what did you got.

Comment: @TirtaDev It gives me a large json formatted message in console. For id it says '845691380670922764'

Comment: Interesting, but does the ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`` error is still there ?

Comment: @TirtaDev I added the `console.log...` in a different cmd. Because when i add it in the commands/fun/britishmeme.js section, it doesnt display anything, just the error

Comment: Can you show the part in your main file where you call the command module

Comment: @user15441631The problem relies on your Command Handler, would you mind adding it on the question too ?

Comment: I can send it, find it on https://shrib.com/#Mohamed5APaRnk

Comment: @TirtaDev I juss realised, the error only comes if i add `const Fetch = require("node-fetch");`.